# If $A \subsetneq C$ then $A \subsetneq B$ or $B \subsetneq C$. Contrapositive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

If $A \subsetneq C$  then $A \subsetneq B$ or $B \subsetneq C$.

Is the contrapositive of this statement If $A \subseteq B$ AND $B \subseteq C$ then $A \subseteq C$.

I asked because I think the first statement is true and if the second statement is the contrapositive then I know how to prove that and therefore prove the first statement.

I am just not sure if the contrapositive causes the *OR* to become an *AND*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are indeed correct. We needed DeMorgans when negating the consequent.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly; it is a little more complex:

If $\bigl(A=B$ or $A\setminus B \neq\varnothing\bigr)$ **and** $\bigl(B=C$ or $B\setminus C \neq\varnothing\bigr)$, then  $\bigl(A=C$ or $A\setminus C\neq\varnothing\bigr)$ .

Anyway, it's clearly false, unless you've hidden some other hypotheses.

Comment: Right; I wrote as though inclusion were a total order. Nevertheless the O.P.'s answer is erroneous: negating strict inclusion is not saying the non-strict inclusion is true.